# Taylor series of a twice-differentiable scalar function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion

I've come across this passage somewhere on wikipedia:

> If $f(t,x)$ is a twice-differentiable scalar function, its expansion in a Taylor series is $$df = \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial t}dt + \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x} dx + \dfrac{1}{2} \dfrac{\partial ^2f}{\partial x^2} dx^2 + ...$$

I'm confused because I thought this would be the Taylor series expansion of $f(t,x)$ itself and not $df$. Can someone explain this expansion?

Comment: Could you provide the link to the page ? Thanks.

Comment: No, the tazlor expansion of $f(t,x)$ would start with $f(0,0)$ or $f(t_0, x_0)$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici It's wiki's page on Ito's lemma, the "informal derivation" part

Comment: It is Ito calculus, a different concept from traditional calculus. Also look at 5xum's comment.